# JQuery ajax fails to execute C# WebMethod consistently

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a peculiar issue occurring that is loosely related to the following post:

jQuery ajax function in external .js file will not call code-behind Webmethod

I have gotten the ajax functioning properly from the client-side. However, I have learned that the WebMethod(s) are not executed every time, or shall I say, consistently.

What I have noticed is that there are certain instances where the ajax functions will save my client-side parameter data, but in some instances the WebMethod in the code behind will not be called and the program will jump directly into the OnClick event which requires the parameters that the WebMethod saves to ensure the application functions properly.

For instance, when multiple calls to the DB are made it will perform the insert properly the first time, but at some point maybe second, third fourth (not consistent) the variables that store the parameters are not changed due to the WebMethod not being called by the ajax function.

It appears that the ajax function is called each time, but the WebMethod fails to execute each and every time.

I have included samples from my code below:

**.aspx** - Onclick and OnClientClick button events embedded in page:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mdlNewCkLines" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="newModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close hidden" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
            <center><h4 class="modal-title">New Check</h4></center>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlNewCk2">
                <div class="panel panel-info" id="newCheckPanel2">
                    <div class=" panel-heading">
                        <h2 class="panel-title"><b>Add Check Lines</b></h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body" style="background-color: #fbfbfb;">
                        <div class="form">
                            <div class="row">
                                <asp:Table runat="server" ID="tblLines" CssClass="data3">
                                    <asp:TableRow>
                                        <asp:TableCell Width="200">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblLines" runat="server" Text="CHECK LINE" CssClass="text-primary" style="padding-left:60px;"/>
                                        </asp:TableCell>
                                        <asp:TableCell Width="300">
                                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" Width="275" CssClass="form-control input-sm" ID="ddlLines" />                                            
                                        </asp:TableCell>
                                    </asp:TableRow>
                                    <asp:TableRow>
                                        <asp:TableCell Width="200">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblLinesAmount" runat="server" Text="AMOUNT&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>$</b>" CssClass="text-primary" style="padding-left:60px;"/>
                                        </asp:TableCell>
                                        <asp:TableCell Width="100">
                                            <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control input-sm" ID="tbLinesAmount" Width="100" runat="server" />
                                        </asp:TableCell>
                                    </asp:TableRow>
                                </asp:Table>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="col-sm-offset-9">
                                        <asp:Button type="button" runat="server" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" OnClick="btnAddNewCkLine_Click" OnClientClick="getCkLineAmt('tbLinesAmount'); saveDdlLinesParms();" ID="btnAddNewCkLine" Text="Submit" UseSubmitBehavior="false"/> <%--OnClick="btnAddNewCkLine_Click"--%>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="row">                    
                <asp:Button type="button" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ID="btnSubmitCkLine" OnClientlick="closeModal('mdlCheckLines');" Text="Finish" UseSubmitBehavior="true" />
                <asp:Button runat="server" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal" ID="cancelNewCk" OnClick="btnCancelNewCk_Click" Text="Cancel" type="button" UseSubmitBehavior="false"/>                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mdlSubmitCkLines" tabindex="-1" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close hidden" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button><center><h4 class="modal-title"><b>Check Writing</b></h4></center>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="well" id="Div7">
                <div class="form">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12"><center>
                            <label class="col-sm-12" style="font-size: 12px;"><b>Check Line Submitted!</b><br></label></center>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <asp:Button ID="btnAnotherCkLine" runat="server" OnClick="btnAnotherCkLine_Click" OnClientClick="hideModal('mdlSubmitCkLines');" type="button" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm" Text="Ok" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnFinishNewCk" runat="server" type="button" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onClientClick="hideModal('mdlSubmitCkLines'); hideModal('mdlCheckLines');" Text="Finish" UseSubmitBehavior="true"/> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**.aspx.cs** - WebMethod that accepts .ajax params including Button events that call JS functions that interact with this particular part of the app:

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static void SaveCkLinesParms(string lineVal, string lineText, string lineAmt)
    {
        string ckLineVal = lineVal;
        string ckLineTxt = lineText;
        string ckLineAmt = lineAmt;

        HttpContext.Current.Session["CheckLineVal"] = ckLineVal;
        HttpContext.Current.Session["CheckLineTxt"] = ckLineTxt;
        HttpContext.Current.Session["CheckLineAmt"] = ckLineAmt;
    }


        protected void btnAddNewCkLine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TreasurersChecksEE TCEE = new TreasurersChecksEE();

        TCEE.ckLineVal    = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["CheckLineVal"];
        TCEE.ckLineTxt = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["CheckLineTxt"];
        TCEE.issueTypeVal = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["Issue Type Value"];
        TCEE.issueTypeTxt = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["Issue Type Text"];
        TCEE.ckLineAmt    = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["CheckLineAmt"];
        TCEE.refundNum    = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["Refund Number"];

        InsertCheckDetail(TCEE.refundNum, TCEE.ckLineVal, TCEE.ckLineAmt);

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Show Modal Popup", "openModal('mdlSubmitCkLines');", true);                      
    }

    protected void btnAnotherCkLine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       TreasurersChecksEE TCEE = new TreasurersChecksEE();

        TCEE.ckLineVal    = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["CheckLineVal"];
        TCEE.ckLineTxt    = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["CheckLineTxt"];
        TCEE.issueTypeVal = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["Issue Type Value"];
        TCEE.issueTypeTxt = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["Issue Type Text"];
        TCEE.ckLineAmt    = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["CheckLineAmt"];
        TCEE.refundNum    = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["Refund Number"];

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Show Modal Popup", "setPanel(" + " '" + ddlAdd.ClientID + "', "
           + " '" + nCkPTitle.ClientID + "', "
           + " '" + manCkEntry.ClientID + "', "
           + " '" + nCkLabel.ClientID + "', "
           + " '" + txtRefNo.ClientID + "', "
           + " '" + TCEE.issueTypeVal + "', "
           + " '" + TCEE.issueTypeTxt + "', "
           + " '" + ddlLines.ClientID + "' "
           + "); openModal('mdlNewCkLines');", true);             
    }
```

**.cs** - DB call and insert:

```
        public void InsertCheckDetail(string refNo, string lineVal, string amt)
    {
        object obj = null;

        if (DBC == null)
            DBC = new DBConn();

        DBC.ExecutePackage("TCMS.TR_CHECK_PROCESSING.DoInsertCheckDetail", out obj, new ParameterDirection[] { ParameterDirection.Input, ParameterDirection.Input, ParameterDirection.Input }, new object[] { refNo, lineVal, amt })
    }
```

**.js** JS .ajax function to send params to code-behind:

```
function saveDdlLinesParms() {
$.ajax({
    url: "TreasurersChecksEE.aspx/SaveCkLinesParms",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ lineVal: ckLineVal, lineText: ckLineTxt, lineAmt: ckLineAmt }),
    datatype: "json",
    context: document.body,
    error: function (xhr, error) {
        console.debug(xhr); console.debug(error);
        }                                     
//                ,success: function (response) {                    
//                    response ? alert("No: " + num + " Txt: " + txt + " RefNo: " + refundNo ) : alert("It didn't work.");
//                }
})};
```

I would be grateful for any help/information regarding this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the code for the `getCkLineAmt` javascript function?

Comment: Here is the code for GetCkLineAmt function  `function getCkLineAmt(parm) {
        parm = 'cphPage_' + parm;
        ckLineAmt = document.getElementById(parm).value;
    }`

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors to the console when it does not run?

Comment: I just tried adding the `async: false` to the ajax attributes, it seems to have alleviated the problem.  I think the JS functions were not completing before the Onclick event was called. Since the Onclick required the data from the ajax call I think the asynchronous calls were at times  completing, well..., out of sequence. Ha!  So I think this has been resolved.  I'm only a year into coding and I have been learning as much as possible. this one is definitely something I will be on the lookout for in the future. Thank you so much for your help!